# salt pillar data not being generated

Tags: salt-stack

I have the following issue whereby I have two salt masters (active/passive), both running 3005.1  . They are both redhat, but one is producing pillar data for minions and the other is not. I should also state that the pillar setup is identical from the same repo.

I am getting the following errors in the salt log files:

[ERROR   ] Got a bad pillar from master, type str, expecting dict:

salt SALT_MINION pillar.items  -l debug

```
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/api.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/api.conf
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/external_auth.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/external_auth.conf
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/gitfs.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/gitfs.conf
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/ldap.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/ldap.conf
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/nodegroups.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/nodegroups.conf
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: dsysaltpr002
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /root/.saltrc
[WARNING ] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/api.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/api.conf
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/external_auth.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/external_auth.conf
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/gitfs.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/gitfs.conf
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/ldap.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/ldap.conf
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/nodegroups.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/nodegroups.conf
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: dsysaltpr002
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /root/.saltrc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Closing AsyncReqChannel instance
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'local_cache' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded local_cache.get_load
[DEBUG   ] Reading minion list from /var/cache/salt/master/jobs/5d/139c5ac4f4fcd6c434136e039b8fc85defdbcbe3e5480db57cb55d2ebc0fe4/.minions.p
[DEBUG   ] get_iter_returns for jid 20230223145728940575 sent to {'SALT_MINION'} will timeout at 14:57:33.946778
[DEBUG   ] jid 20230223145728940575 return from SALT_MINION
[DEBUG   ] return event: {'SALT_MINION': {'ret': {}, 'retcode': 0, 'jid': '20230223145728940575'}}
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'nested' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded nested.output
SALT_MINION:
>!     ----------
[DEBUG   ] jid 20230223145728940575 found all minions {'SALT_MINION'}
[DEBUG   ] Closing IPCMessageSubscriber instance
```

Has anyone seen anything similar?

salt SALT_MINION pillar.items  -l debug

was expecting the minion data to come back.

Comment: `salt -l debug <target> <module>` unfortunately only returns the master's debug information. Often, the log from the minion is more interesting. So far my work around is to run:  `salt <target> cmd.run 'salt-call -l debug <module>'` This will return debug log information from the module/state execution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, unreal.

So I went through the top.sls pillar file and started commenting-out all the entries. I got to a nodegroup that started the behaviour.

In the nodegroup.conf file I had a nodegroup entry of:

```yaml
NODEGROUP1:
  - server1
  - server2
  -
```

Notice the `-` with no server. That causes the behaviour.